# How do I reload/reinstall a kernel extension driver, solving this error: Filesystem error: Invalid ownership (501:0) should be (0:0)?

Tags: driver, kernel-extensions, sip

For solving a problem with a drive, I had to uninstall/unload an external SSD Samsung driver.
Doing this, was reasonable easy: disable `SIP` in Recover (`csrutil disable`), rebooting, `sudo kextunload /...`, then `rm -rf /...`. Driver unloaded and gone.

I backuped the driver thinking doing the opposite was that trivial, but looks it's not.
I copied back the file in:  `/Library/Extensions`, then I tried to reload the driver.

I tried with `sudo` (`sudo kextload /Library/Extensions/SamsungPortableSSDDriver.kext`), disabling again `SIP`, even from root shell (`sudo -i`). Nothing seems to work.

This is the error message:

```
Filesystem error: Invalid ownership (501:0) should be (0:0) on /Library/Extensions/SamsungPortableSSDDriver.kext
```

Any clue? Thank you.

Comment: The error message is rather specific already, isn’t it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the ownership of the extension, do the following (and make sure you are in the correct directory before running `chown -R`):

```
cd /Library/Extensions
sudo chown -R root:wheel SamsungPortableSSDDriver.kext
```

This will change ownership recursively and you won't get mentioned error.

Then you should be able to do

```
% sudo kextload /Library/Extensions/SamsungPortableSSDDriver.kext
Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil load -p /Library/Extensions/SamsungPortableSSDDriver.kext
```

Comment: @Tetsujin In what sense? It doesn't apply just to the driver ('SamsungPortableSSDDriver.kext') and all its subdirectories?

Comment: @Tetsujin "Take care to not run recursive chown on the root '/' directory or any other system directory". (I double checked also with man chown -R option) This is not the case, isn't it? `sudo chown -R root:wheel SamsungPortableSSDDriver.kext`, is not applied in ., .., * or / 
Anything bad you already see in the above precise command string or is just a general warning? Thx.

Comment: @Tetsujin I tested `chown root:wheel -R [folder]`. Using secure directories for the purpose, I first created anidated folders with subfolders. I checked with `ls -l` all ownerships below and above the experimental folder-with-subfolders. Ownership didn't change in any of the below, yes in the intended/above (the danger you are referring has to do with the case of not being aware that a symbolic link to a root [hierarchy below] folder is in the subfolders?). Thx.

Comment: @Tetsujin In which specific cases does `chown -R` go up? I’m only aware of the case which is listed in the man page (`chown -R .*`), this doesn’t apply here.

Comment: @Tetsujin In the specific case, it is needed. The .kext directory structure is similar to .app, and ownership change on all files/directories is most likely required.

Comment: Ah, right. I'm going to shovel all my comments gracelessly into the bin ;))